# Python add sequential value array to dict

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

For example i have dict python

```
dict = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```

and array

```
arr = ['4', '5', '6']
```

I want add sequential value array to dict

```
dict1 = {'a': '4', 'b': '5', 'c': '6'}
```

Please suggest a specific solution.

Comment: Please do not name a variable `dict`

Comment: Just key mapping exactly to value :D

Comment: You're relying on the keys of the dict having a specific order. Dicts are unordered; they make no guarantees about what order their entries will appear in.

Comment: @user2357112 OP does provide a dictionary that maps keys to values, `'1' < '2' < '3'`.

Comment: if `dict = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}` was `my_dict = {'z' : '1', 'm' : '23', 'a' : '9'}` what would your expected output be?

Comment: @Akavall : I reckon we should ignore the existing values and their order, since they're going to be replaced. I _suspect_ that the OP doesn't realise that a plain `dict` is unordered, and wants to associate the new values with the _keys_ in alphabetical order, as per vil's answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
>>> arr = ['4', '5', '6']
>>> dict(zip(sorted(d), arr))
{'a': '4', 'c': '6', 'b': '5'}
```

Comment: `keys()` is not required, becausing iterating dictionary yields keys:  `dict(zip(sorted(d), arr))`

Comment: Well this will not work if the poster does not change the name of his variable since he now has masked the `dict` function!

Comment: This is going to run into problems when the keys of `d` become `'pizza'`, `'bagels'`, and `'chicken'`, and `sorted` suddenly doesn't produce the right order.

Comment: I think sorting should be done based on values, perhaps `int` values of values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> import string
>>> arr = ['4', '5', '6']
>>> # dict(zip(sorted(original_dict), arr))
>>> dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, arr))
{'b': '5', 'c': '6', 'a': '4'}
```

BTW, don't name a varialbe `dict`. It will shadows builtin type/function [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but the below code snippet does what you intend in your question.

```
import os
dict = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
arr = ['4', '5', '6']

dict1 = {}
dictAsList = dict.items()
i = 0
for key in sorted(dict):
    try:
        dict1[key] = arr[i]
    except:
        pass
    i = i+1
print dict1
```

Comment: `iterkeys()` is not required. `sorted(dict)` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionary doesn't have order. So I don't get what sequential means in dictionary.

If you just want to set all value to another value you can do like this.

```
d = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
arr = ['4', '5', '6']
print dict(zip(d.keys(), arr))
#{'a': '4', 'c': '5', 'b': '6'}
```

If you want to set value as same order you can do like this.(You need change your data structure)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')])
arr = ['4', '5', '6']
print dict(zip(d.keys(), arr))
#{'a': '4', 'c': '6', 'b': '5'}
```